# How to order pieces

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a problem showing the contents of the pieces.

I would like the pieces to be shown in "apostrophe-pieces-pages" by their date of creation. I've tried mongoDB queries to sort them by the "createdAt" field through the "BeforeSend" module, however this result appears on all pages and I don't want that result.

Would there be any way to sort by creation date that only affects the page of the piece?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort the pieces as they appear on the index? Not sure what you mean by `sort by creation date that only affects the page of the piece`

Comment: I want to sorter the pieces by date. My idea is to create a calendar and click on a day to show the content of that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apostrophe-pieces has a top level option for adding a simple sort filter to your index. In your pieces subclass (your module that extends `apostrophe-pieces`, not `apostrophe-pieces-pages`) you should be able to add a `sort` filter to your module options for ordering.

```
module.exports = {
  label: 'My Piece',
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  sort: { createdAt: -1 } // reverse chronological order
  // ... other configuration
};
```

More on `sort` at https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-docs/server-apostrophe-cursor#sort-value

More on the MongoDB `sort` method and what it takes here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

If you wanted to create completely custom orderings, the `apostrophe-pieces-orderings-bundle` might be helpful https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-pieces-orderings-bundle

Answer (score 0):

In apostrophe 3 the ordering can be set by:

```html
module.exports = {
  extend: '@apostrophecms/piece-type',
  options: {
    sort: {
      publishDate: -1
    }
  },
  ...
}
```